# Periodicity of a series of points

Tags: periodic-functions

I have a series of 2-D points. I want to analyze if there is any pattern in this series. Also, if the series is somehow repeating, can I extract a smaller series of points to analyze instead of the complete list of points?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Fourier transformation of data will help to find a pattern. Try to Google about it.

Comment: Are these points' series finite? Can you provide at least some mathematical form of this series?

Comment: If you want to read mathematica code, there is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176518/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-period-of-a-repeating-list-in-mathematica But without more information I can't help. (the accepted answer there has a bug)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you calculate the autocorrelation over all points, that should give you a good measure of periodicity.

See for introduction [here>>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)

or general literature on signal processing or stochastics.

In general the more points you include, the more reliable your result might be.